# Filename changed after compiliation for java

Tags: java, javac

So i had this .java file named as 'anagram.java'.
After compiling with javac the resultant .class file i get is named 'Anagram.class' (with a capital A)
This may seem inconsequential but so far, I've managed to get the same name in both the code and compiled file. Would anyone know why this happened?
[You can see a picture of the commandline here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIxIA.png)

Comment: is your class called Anagram or anagram?

Comment: What's the name of the class in `anagram.java`?  I'll bet it's `Anagram` (and not `anagram`).  Thus the name of the `.class` file is `Angram.class`, not `anagram.class`, in spite of the source file being `anagram.java` rather than `Anagram.java`.   In other words, the name of the `.class` file comes from the name of the class, not the name of the Java source file.

Comment: .class file take up the name of the Class that contains the main method, so if it is `class Anagram`, it'll be Anagram.class

Comment: Oh right, I see. my class was named Anagram. That makes more sense but i had been under the impression that the main class has to have the same name as the source file. I'm surprised the code even ran. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that javac is case-insensitive for Windows, but not for Linux, for example. Your class name in the anagram.java file is capitalized, i.e. it is class Anagram (as it should be), so javac is using this capitalized version to make your class file. In general, keep java filenames capitalized as well since it is convention, and depending on the operating system, javac may not work with discrepancies in capitalization.

Comment: No worries at all!

Comment: In what circumstances is `javac` case-insensitive in filenames? On Linux `javac` expects public classes to be defined in files with the same name, including same case. If this answer is correct at all, I don't think it's correct for Linux.

Comment: \@KevinBoone You're right; it's case insensitive for Windows, but not for Linux. I was defaulting to Windows answer. I'll update the answer. Hopefully it's now satisfactory.

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder -- is it `javac` that is case insensitive in filename, or Windows itself? Or perhaps `javac` has to be, because Windows is?

Comment: I assume it is the latter, that javac must be case insensitive because Windows itself is.